# Tkinter text widget adding tabs to selected text

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, tkinter, textbox

I am trying to create a text editor for python using tkinter. When the user highlights lines of text and presses tab, I want the program to add a tab in front of each line of selected text, similar to what Idle does. This is the function I have so far:

```
    self.TextBox.bind('<KeyPress-Tab>', self.tabtext)

def tabtext(self, e):
    try:
        untabbed = self.TextBox.selection_get() # get selected text
        lines = untabbed.split('\n') # splits into a list of lines
        tabbed = ''

        for i in range(len(lines)):
            lines[i] = '    ' + lines[i] # adds tabs to each line

        tabbed = '\n'.join(lines) # joins list with newline character

        old = self.TextBox.get("1.0", tk.END) # gets old text
        new = old.replace(untabbed, tabbed) # replaces all instances of  highlighted
# text with new text

        self.TextBox.delete('1.0', tk.END) # deletes old text
        self.TextBox.insert(tkinter.END, new) # adds new text

        return 'break' # prevents it from deletion

    except:
        return
```

This code works, however if the selected text appears in the text box more than once, it will add tabs to each instance of the selected code. Is there any way to resolve this, maybe involving finding the position of the selected text. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're replacing all of the text rather than just the text that was selected? Why not just delete the selected text and replace it with the computed text?

Comment: No, there's not a reason, I just didn't know that was possible, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just replace the selected code rather that deleting and re-inserting all of the text.

The first step is to get the index of the start of the line for the selection:

```
index = self.TextBox.index("sel.first linestart")
```

Next, delete all of the lines in the selection:

```
self.TextBox.delete("sel.first linestart", "sel.last lineend")
```

Finally, insert the new text

```
    self.TextBox.insert(index, tabbed)
```

### Alternate method

Though, if all you're doing is inserting tags, you don't need to delete-and-replace. You can also just insert a tab for every line in the selected range. All you have to do is iterate over the lines. It would look something like this:

```
def tabtext(self, e):
    last = self.TextBox.index("sel.last linestart")
    index = self.TextBox.index("sel.first linestart")
    while self.TextBox.compare(index,"<=", last):
        self.TextBox.insert(index, "    ")
        index = self.TextBox.index("%s + 1 line" % index)
    return "break"
```

Comment: Thank you! This has helped a lot