# Multiline insert selection tkinter Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to add a feature to my Text widget so that I can select multiple lines and comment it out. I currently have it working for single lines but am having trouble detecting the insert spanning multiple characters/lines. How do I get this kind of information. I know it is possible to detect it as you can remove multiple characters/lines at once with the Delete button. I want to comment out these chunks by adding a hashtag at the beginning of each line and it should also be able to remove multiline comments. How would I get the insert info to do such a thing?

Current commenting code:

```
#In __init__:
        self.text.bind("<Command-slash>", self.make_comment)
#Later...
    def make_comment(self, event):
        self_anchor = (str(self.text.index("insert")).split("."))[0]
        if self.text.get(self_anchor + ".0", self_anchor + ".1") != "#":
            self.text.insert(float("{}.0".format(self_anchor)), "#")
        else:
            self.text.delete(self_anchor + ".0", self_anchor + ".1")
```

[image: Gif] [Seperate link](https://ibb.co/tDjK90c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [this answer by Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43143092/16775594), I've solved this problem. I'll explain the code and how it works, but if you just want the working code, it'll be at the bottom of this answer.

---

In order to comment/uncomment all the lines in the user's selection, we need to know each line number. This can be done by using Python's `range()` function and the start and end line numbers of the user's selection.

To get the start line of the user's selection, we use this code:

```py
first_line = self.text.index("sel.first").split(".")[0]
```

`sel.first` just means "the start index of the user's selection." Similarly, if we want to get the *end* line of the user's selection, we do the same thing but use `sel.last`:

```py
last_line = self.text.index("sel.last").split(".")[0]
```

Then, we use the `range()` function to loop through both of those lines and each line in between them:

```py
for line in range(first_line, last_line + 1):
    # Comment or uncomment each line
    ...
```

Note we use `last_line + 1` to make sure we're including the last line, since Python's `range()` function stops *before* it gets to the second number.

Now, the only problem with this code is that if the user has *not* selected something, you get a `_tkinter.TclError` saying that `text doesn't contain any characters tagged with "sel"`. So in order to be able to comment/uncomment a single line, you need to insert a `try`/`except` block:

```py
try:
    first_line = self.text.index("sel.first").split(".")[0]
    last_line = self.text.index("sel.last").split(".")[0]
    for line in range(first_line, last_line + 1):
        # Comment or uncomment each line
        ...
except tkinter.TclError:
    # Comment or uncomment a single line
    ...
```

The rest of the code looks very similar to what you already have; you check if the first character on the line is a `#`, if it is, then uncomment the line, if not, then comment the line.

There's just two more things:

1. At the end of `self.make_comment()`, you might need to add `return "break"`; on my system at least, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> command also selects all the text. Returning `"break"` at the end of the function prevents it from doing that.
2. When looping and commenting multiple lines, you need to make sure that the current line number isn't greater than the number of newlines in the text. For example:

```py
for line in range(first_line, last_line+1):
    if line <= int(self.text.get("1.0", "end").count("\n")):
        # Comment or uncomment the lines
        ...
```

---

All that said, here is a complete reproducible example. You can comment/uncomment multiple lines at a time, or just one line, depending on how things are selected:

```py
import tkinter

class Window(tkinter.Tk):
    """The main window."""
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # Our text widget
        self.text = tkinter.Text(self)
        with open(__file__) as f:
            self.text.insert("1.0", f.read())
        self.text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        
        # Bind the text widget
        self.text.bind("<Control-slash>", self.make_comment)
        self.text.bind("<Control-a>", self.select_all)

    def select_all(self, *args):
        self.text.tag_add("sel", "1.0", "end")
        return "break"
        
    def make_comment(self, event):
        
        # If this fails with an error, we know that the user only selected one line
        try:
            
            # Get the line number of the start and the end of the selection
            first_line = int(self.text.index("sel.first").split(".")[0])
            last_line = int(self.text.index("sel.last").split(".")[0])
            
            # Loop through all the selected lines and comment or uncomment them
            for line in range(first_line, last_line+1):
                # This is to make sure that a # isn't added to something that isn't a line
                if line <= int(self.text.get("1.0", "end").count("\n")):
                    if self.text.get("{}.0".format(line), "{}.1".format(line)) != "#":
                        self.text.insert("{}.0".format(line), "#")
                    else:
                        self.text.delete("{}.0".format(line), "{}.1".format(line))
        except tkinter.TclError:
            
            # Get the line number of the current cursor position
            insert = self.text.index("insert").split(".")[0]
            
            # Comment or uncomment the current line
            if self.text.get("{}.0".format(insert), "{}.1".format(insert)) != "#":
                self.text.insert("{}.0".format(insert), "#")
            else:
                self.text.delete("{}.0".format(insert), "{}.1".format(insert))
        return "break"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Window().mainloop()
```

Comment: This works so well! Thank you so much! I did have one question though. When the user uses </kbd>Command+a</kbd> and uses </kbd>Command+/</kbd> it inserts an extra hashtag on the last character. Any thoughts on how to fix this? Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @TRCK Glad to help! What do you mean by the last character? The last character on the line, or the last character in the whole text widget? If you meant the latter, that's how it's supposed to work; every selected line gets commented. If you don't want empty lines to get commented, you can add (or ask me to add) some code to check if the line is empty before commenting it. Alternatively, I could just remove that last empty line from the example.

Comment: It adds a hashtag to the last character of the last line. It's something super negligible but I just thought I'd ask. I can add a gif of the problem.

Comment: I have added the gif

Comment: @TRCK Ah, I see... I'll look into that, and edit my answer if I find a solution. The problem is with using `last_line+1`; apparently, `tkinter`'s select-all selects a non-existent line-after-last-line, and that's picked up by the `sel` tag. However, since that line-after-last-line isn't actually a line, the character is just added to the end of the _real_ last line. Weird.

Comment: Thanks! Let me know once its done! Maybe we add an overall if statement to see if it doesn't have the last line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243836/discussion-between-trck-and-sylvester-kruin).